# How do you centre align N lines of text

Tags: c, formatting, user-input

Apparently there is no standardised way to centre align text in C, so what I

wanted to know is how do I write an if statement to centre align the next N lines

of text. For example if the program finds `.ce2` in the text file it should

print the next two lines in the centre of the page then carry on as normal.

```
.ce2 This is my heading
Lesson 1
Task 2
```

Output:

```
                       This is my heading

                           Lesson 1
```

`Task 2`

Below is the code I have written, I implemented the `.br` feature to break the

sentence and also the `.sp` feature to add blank lines into the text.

```
int main(void) {
FILE *fp = NULL;
char file_name[257] = {'\0'};
char line[61] = {'\0'};
char word[61] = {'\0'};
int out = 0;
int blanks;
int space;

printf ( "Enter file name:\n");
scanf ( " %256[^\n]", file_name);

if ( ( fp = fopen ( file_name, "r")) == NULL) {
    printf ( "could not open file\n");
    return 1;
}

while ( ( fscanf ( fp, "%60s", word)) == 1) { //breaks the sentence after .br
    if ( strcmp ( word, ".br") == 0) {
        printf ( "%s\n", line);
        line[0] = '\0';
        out = 1;
    }

    if ( strncmp ( word, ".sp", 3) == 0) { // creates n amount of spaces after .sp
        if ( ( sscanf ( &word[3], "%d", &blanks)) == 1) {
        printf ( "%s\n", line);
            while ( blanks) {
                blanks--;
                printf ( "\n");
                                }
            line[0] = '\0';
            out = 1;
                        }

    if ( strncmp ( word, ".ce", 3) == 0) { // centre the next n lines
        if ( ( sscanf ( &word[3], "%d", &space)) == 1) {
   //this is the if statement I am stuck at on what to include                
}
            line[0] = '\0';
            out = 1;
                        }
```

Comment: What is supposed to happen if the text cannot be perfectly centered? Also, please format your code. It's a bit hard to read with braces all over the place.

Comment: What is `line`? Where is it filled? Please format your code in a standard way so we can read it..

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I have added the start of the code to make it more understandable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printf` does not provide a mechanism for centering text, but it does provide a mechanism for right-justifying text (the field width) and a mechanism for specifying the field width as an argument. Putting these two together, it is easy to center the text:

```
int print_centered(FILE* f, const char* str, int width) {
  int len = strlen(str);
  if (len < width) 
    return fprintf(f, "%*s\n", (width + len) / 2, str);
  else /* Line is too long to fit */
    return fprintf(f, "%s\n", str);
}
```

If you wanted to truncate lines which were too long to fit, you could use the "precision", which in the case of `%s` formats limits the length of the string to be printed:

```
int print_centered_or_truncated(FILE* f, const char* str, int width) {
  int len = strlen(str);
  if (len < width) 
    return fprintf(f, "%*s\n", (width + len) / 2, str);
  else /* Line is too long to fit */
    return fprintf(f, "%.*s\n", width, str);
}
```

See [`man fprintf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3.html) for more details.

Comment: your code will work but I don't think it relates to my kind of problem as I have a given file which contains `.ce2` meaning the next two lines should be centred but your code doesn't change anything to my existing code

Comment: @jayjay: depending on how you look at it, it gives you a function you can call to center a line, which leabes you only with the code to read the lines to be centred, or it gives you a model to base your code on. It does not provide "please write my code for me", which is not what SO is about.

Answer (score 0):

This function will take the width of the buffer where you want to center your text, the format and any other parameters that printf accepts and it will truncate if the width is smaller than the output buffer.

```
#include <stdarg.h>

/***********************************
 * This function will center a     *
 * buffer of size 'width', and     *
 * it will truncate larger strings *
 **********************************/
int center_printf(int width, const char* format, ...)
{
   char *tmp = NULL, *output = NULL;
   int length, leading_spaces, ret;
   va_list args;

   if ( width <= 0 )                // Abort on incorrect width.
   {
      ret = -1;
      goto cleanup;
   }

   tmp = (char *)malloc ( width );
   if (tmp == NULL)
   {
      ret = -1;
      goto cleanup;
   }

   output = (char *)malloc ( width );
   if ( output == NULL )
   {
      ret = -1;
      goto cleanup;
   }

   va_start ( args, format );
   memset ( output, 0x20, width );    // Fill the output buffer with spaces.

   length = vsnprintf ( tmp, width, format, args );
   leading_spaces = ( length >= width ) ? 0 : (width - length)/ 2;
   memcpy ( output + leading_spaces, tmp, length );

   ret = printf ( output );
   va_end( args );

cleanup:
   if ( tmp != NULL )
      free ( tmp );
   if ( output != NULL )
        free ( output );

   return ret;
}
```

EDIT:
Fixed my function as per chux and rici's comments.

```
int center_printf(int width, const char* format, ...)
{
   char *output = NULL;
   int length, ret;
   va_list args;

   if ( width <= 0 )                // Abort on incorrect width.
   {
      ret = -1;
      goto cleanup;
   }

   output = (char *)malloc ( width + 1 );
   if (output == NULL)
   {
      ret = -1;
      goto cleanup;
   }

   va_start ( args, format );
   length = vsnprintf ( output, width + 1, format, args );
   ret = printf ( "%*s", ( length >= width ) ? 0 : (width + length)/2 , output );
   va_end( args );

cleanup:
   if ( output != NULL )
      free ( output );

   return ret;
}
```

Usage:

```
center_printf (50, "%s: testing 123", __FUNCTION__);
```

Comment: `if ( width <= 0 )   { ...    goto cleanup;` does a `if ( tmp != NULL )  free ( tmp );` on uninitialized `tmp`.

Comment: I think this way is far too complex for me, i'm looking for a simpler way similar to the way I implement `.sp` and `.br`

Comment: This solution is unnecessarily complicated, yes. It also has two glaring errors: (1) A string which can contain `width` characters requires `malloc(width+1)` (two places, although there is no need for the second copy since you could output the necessary spaces with printf); and (2) It is unsafe to use an arbitrary string as the format for `printf`. Use `fputs(str, stdout)` or `printf("%s", str)` instead. (What happens if there is a percent in the string to be printed?)

Comment: I fixed my function using your comments and answer. Thanks for the input, I actually use it and one of my requirements is to take the format parameter as well as any other variables sent, as if it were a normal printf function. Ah. I see what you mean by passing a percent sign escaped like this \%. The following printf would be in problems. Thanks. Working on it. If I had the points I would upvote your comment.